# PhoneGap App mysteriously stopped working on iOS Emulator and Device. Stripped down code, still broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I was creating an ionicframework/cordova/phonegap app but following some updates I'm no longer able to test it on the iOS emulator or device.

I've stripped out the majority of my code just to see if I was doing something wrong. I'm unfortunately getting no error messages, and I'm wondering whether it's a problem with my environment? I'm using Mac OSX 10.9.3.

I am [unable to log to the console at this point](https://github.com/sebinsua/ionic-app/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js#L9), however [we do get to this line](https://github.com/sebinsua/ionic-app/blob/master/www/js/app.js#L95).

If you `git clone` [this project](https://github.com/sebinsua/ionic-app) you should be able to run `npm install` and then `gulp emulate` to see exactly what I mean - assuming no issues with the installation.

This is what I see inside the console.log produced by `ionic emulate ios`.

> 2014-06-08 13:46:00.612 Ionic App[83437:70b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.623 Ionic App[83437:70b] Unlimited access to network resources
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.650 Ionic App[83437:70b] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 6.989956ms
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.650 Ionic App[83437:70b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 7.485032ms
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.781 Ionic App[83437:70b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.932 Ionic App[83437:70b] Finished load of: file:///Users/sebinsua/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/CC48195C-28FF-4138-88C4-90E02AA044CA/Ionic%20App.app/www/index.html#/
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.955 Ionic App[83437:70b] adding proxy for Contacts
>   2014-06-08 13:46:00.956 Ionic App[83437:70b] Ionic is ready.

I even have a repository in which I [removed most of the dependencies](https://github.com/sebinsua/ionic-app/tree/still-broken) and that's also playing up...

Does anybody know why it's not working? Can I troubleshoot my environment in anyway? I was just planning on finishing my MVP and then going ahead and rewriting it with Swift but at this point I'm wondering whether to bother. There's something really annoying with the fact it's silently failing with no error messages. I don't know what to troubleshoot. Any way of getting more errors/verbosity than I have?

The funny thing is that it's loading the template and not running the code inside the controller that's related to this.

If I just bring up a local server and use the browser then it all works?! Does that mean something is wrong with Cordova?